# Polynomial is in the kernel of a ring homomorphism if and only if all coefficients are in the kernel of another ring homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Let $f$ be a ring homomorphism from $R$ to $R'$. Then define $g$ from $R[x]$ to $R'[x]$ to be a ring homomorphism where $g(\sum_{i=0}^n a_i x^i) = \sum_{i=0}^n f(a_i)x^i$.

I want to show that $\sum_{i=0}^n a_i x^i \in \ker(g)$ implies that, for any $i \in \{0, \ldots, n\}$, $f(a_i) \in \ker(f)$.

I started the proof by applying the definitions and got to the statement

$$\sum_{i=0}^n f(a_i) x^i = 0_{R'}$$

where $0_{R'}$ is the additive identity in $R'$ and also in $R'[x]$.

From here, it seems intuitive that $f(a_i) = 0_{R'}$, but how can I formalize this more rigorously?

Comment: Your $g$ seems to be defined fron $R[x]$ to $R'[x]$, not $R$ to $R'$ as you assert.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, sorry about that, I've updated the question

Comment: Do induction on the degree.

Comment: You need to know when two polynomials are equal, or more specifically, when a polynomial is equal to zero.